# Is there any way i can do the AJAX pagination links without refreshing the page and changing the URL?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

## Wordpress Pagination Links with AJAX, without changing URL and Refreshing the Page.

Hello guys, how are you? I have some problem with the pagination links, so i want to have 12 posts displayed on my frontend when i load the page, and ofcourse to have dynamicly pagination with 1,2,3 and arrows, i think you understand me :D .

NOTE: I am not allowed to use jQuery into my functions and script tags.

So just to have some example like this:

```
$args_Games = new WP_Query([
'post_type' => 'games',
'posts_per_page' => '12',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'date'
]);

<div class="game-wrapper">
@posts($args_Games)
   <h1>@title</h1>
@endposts
</div>
<div class="pagination-links">
    <li class="paginate-link"></li>
</div>
```

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#definition) to retrieve your posts' data, then render it.